# Combining multiple jsons into one json python

Tags: python, json, flask

I have three jsons:

```
a = {'name':'Tyler', 'd1': [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]], 'd2': [[2,2],[4,4],[6,6]]}
b = {'name':'Matt', 'd1': [[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]], 'd2': [[6,6],[8,8],[10,10]]}
c = {'name':'Sarah', 'd1': [[2,1],[4,2],[6,3]], 'd2': [[4,2],[8,4],[12,6]]}
```

I am trying to combine a,b,c into one json such that they have the following format

```
d = [{'name':'Tyler', 'd1': [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]], 'd2': [[2,2],[4,4],[6,6]]},{'name':'Matt', 'd1': [[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]], 'd2': [[6,6],[8,8],[10,10]]},{'name':'Sarah', 'd1': [[2,1],[4,2],[6,3]], 'd2': [[4,2],[8,4],[12,6]]}]
```

This json d is going to be passed into flask so that I can use it in a d3 chart.

I have tried creating a list d = [a,b,c] and then letting e = json.dumps(d) but this does not work. I have also tried to create an empty dictionary and add the a,b,c in and then dump this to json but this does not work. Are there any nice implementations for this? Thanks

Comment: What's the issue with `json.dumps([a,b,c])`?

Comment: So that works but it gives me ["{\"name\": and then the data like that]. I think that it is doing so because I am using json.dumps before. I know what to do now, thanks!

Comment: Yes, using `dumps` multiple times might cause that. If you have further issues edit the question and post the exact code that's giving problems, otherwise people answering are just making guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `json.dumps` with a list:

```
import json

a = {'name':'Tyler', 'd1': [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]], 'd2': [[2,2],[4,4],[6,6]]}
b = {'name':'Matt', 'd1': [[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]], 'd2': [[6,6],[8,8],[10,10]]}
c = {'name':'Sarah', 'd1': [[2,1],[4,2],[6,3]], 'd2': [[4,2],[8,4],[12,6]]}

print(json.dumps([a, b, c]))
```

Output, formatted for easier reading:

```
[{"d2": [[2, 2], [4, 4], [6, 6]], "d1": [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]], "name": "Tyler"}, 
 {"d2": [[6, 6], [8, 8], [10, 10]], "d1": [[3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]], "name": "Matt"}, 
 {"d2": [[4, 2], [8, 4], [12, 6]], "d1": [[2, 1], [4, 2], [6, 3]], "name": "Sarah"}]
```